# Rails : bad habit of using .html.erb as helpers?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am using a lot of .html.erb partials as "helpers". I'm not sure if this is a really bad habit or not.

*main_file.html.erb*

```
render 'shared/some_helper.html.erb', 
  param_1: param_1, 
  param_2: param_2,
  ...,
  optional_param_1: optional_param_1,
  ...
```

*shared/some_helper.html.erb*

```
<%
optional_param_1 ||= optional_param_1_default
optional_param_2 ||= optional_param_2_default
...
# Some additional logic
%>

<!-- The HTML that uses the params -->
```

I *feel* this is justified because my helpers are more about HTML than ruby/rails.

But is there actually a better way to do it (that remains as convenient) ? Maybe define some function in applicaton_helper.erb that would output the HTML ? But then I won't be able to write HTML...

Comment: These are not *helpers* in the Rails way but just *shared partial views* and it is perfectly fine to use them like this. Also, you can write HTML in your ruby files (especially in the Helpers since they have direct access to methods like `html_safe`: `def breakline ; "<br/>".html_safe ; end` is a valid rails method outputting HTML-interpreted code)

Comment: I agree with MrYoshiji.  Just be sure to keep them together (ie. in 'shared') to keep your sanity.

Comment: Yes about HTML in ruby files with html_safe, but it is considered as a string, and it will break syntax highlighting. Also it would mean using `\"` for every html attribute `class=\"tedious\"`

Comment: What about `content_tag(:br)`? Pure ruby code generating HTML. Pretty usefull for constructing tables via helpers, for example

Comment: Hmm nice I didn't know about this one. But then I'd rather stick with more "visual" HTML.

Comment: Oh yes also when I do `optional_param ||= default_value`, is it polluting the global view, or does `optional_param` disappear from memory after the partial is done rendering ?